Error in GET /fetch-transactions: TypeError: s.Wallet is not a constructor
I'm currently trying to fetch-transactions in a serverless function using vercel and getting this error:
    Error in GET /fetch-transactions: TypeError: s.Wallet is not a constructor

Is there a special way to connect when doing so from a server?
Here is my code:
    export const runtime = 'nodejs';
    export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
    
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
    import { getPrismaClient } from '../utils/prisma';
    import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
    
    export async function GET(request) {
      const prisma = getPrismaClient();
      const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
      const address = searchParams.get('address');
    
      if (!address) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Address is required' }, { status: 400 });
      }
    
      try {
        const rpcEndpoint = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RPC_ENDPOINT;
        const serverKeypairBase64 = process.env.SERVER_KEYPAIR_BASE64;
    
        if (!rpcEndpoint) {
          throw new Error('RPC endpoint is not defined in NEXT_PUBLIC_RPC_ENDPOINT');
        }
    
        if (!serverKeypairBase64) {
          throw new Error('Server keypair is not defined in SERVER_KEYPAIR_BASE64');
        }
    
        const serverKeypairUint8Array = Uint8Array.from(
          JSON.parse(Buffer.from(serverKeypairBase64, 'base64').toString())
        );
    
        console.log('DEBUG CHECK 1');
        const serverKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(serverKeypairUint8Array);
        console.log('DEBUG CHECK 2');
        const wallet = new anchor.Wallet(serverKeypair);
        console.log('DEBUG CHECK 3');
        const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(rpcEndpoint, 'confirmed');
        console.log('DEBUG CHECK 4');
        const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {});
        anchor.setProvider(provider);
        const programId = new anchor.web3.PublicKey('PROGRAM_ID');
        const idl = await anchor.Program.fetchIdl(programId, provider);
        const program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId, provider);

The server logs:
DEBUG CHECK 1

DEBUG CHECK 2 

and then the error
Thanks for your help!

what version of @coral-xyz/anchor are you using?

Consider updating the wallet constructor (use web3 instead of anchor):
import { Keypair, Connection } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { AnchorProvider, setProvider, Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';

// Replace anchor.Wallet with Keypair-based wallet for server
const serverKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(serverKeypairUint8Array);
const connection = new Connection(rpcEndpoint, 'confirmed');

